# Errors on Xubuntu 14.04 Startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, error-logging

I recently changed my Dell Latitude E6440 Board. I am using Xubuntu 14.04.
I get those errors at start up. Here are the errors from the dmesg.

```
[    2.812926] usb 2-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.992968] usb 2-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.245021] usb 2-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.421065] usb 2-1.8: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    3.452032] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.005107] usb 2-1.8: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[    4.485193] usb 2-1.8: device not accepting address 7, error -32
```

Any idea?